# Show that given $\epsilon > 0,$ there exist $N>0$ and $M>0$ so that $\int_{\{x:|x|>N\}} f< \epsilon \text{ and } \int_{\{x:f(x)>M\}} f<\epsilon.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Can someone please help me prove the following?

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is nonnegative and integrable. Show that given $\epsilon > 0,$ there exist $N>0$ and $M>0$ so that $$\int_{\{x:|x|>N\}} f< \epsilon \text{ and } \int_{\{x:f(x)>M\}} f<\epsilon.$$

My idea: We need to find a simple function $\eta$ on $N$ and $M$ that have finite support, so let $\epsilon >0$ and we know by definition of the integral for nonnegative measurable functions that there exists bounded measurable functions of finite support, that is $h\le f.$

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "simple function $\eta$ on $N$ and $M$." I suspect this is an exercise related to the monotone convergence theorem (and/or Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem), so you want functions $f_N(x)$ such that $f_N(x)\nearrow f(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I will assume a slightly general version, namely when $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R\cup\{\pm \infty\}$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Consider $f_n:=\chi_{\{x\in \Bbb R:|x|>n\}}\cdot f$, then $f_n\to 0$ pointwise a.e. and $|f_n|\leq |f|$. So, Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem gives $$\lim\int f_n =0.$$

Next, consider $g_n:= \chi_{\{x\in \Bbb R:|f(x)|>n\}}\cdot f$, then $g_n\to 0$ pointwise a.e. Note that we are using the fact here that $f$ is integrable implies $m\big(|f|^{-1}(\infty)\big)=0$, in case $f$ only takes real value then it is obvious. Also, $|g_n|\leq f$. So, Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem gives $$\lim\int g_n =0.$$